Can no-load conditions cause issues with an LDO?
I use an LDO (MIC2941A) to supply constant current (~100mA) for charging a large super capacitor. Input voltage to the LDO is 12V. When the super capacitor is charged to circa 12V, there is no other load on the LDO.
Will this cause any trouble or damage to the LDO over time?
From experience I know that many linear regulators and LDOs will raise the output voltage if the minimum load current is not met. Since this would only happen in my case when the LDO output voltage is already very close to the input voltage, it does not concern me. But I wonder if there are other potential issues that could arise from not meeting the minimum load requirement.
Additional details: I have a 10uF tantalum bypass capacitor right at the LDO output, before the current limiting resistor. LDO input voltage will not rise above 12V. The capacitance of the super capacitor is 0.3F, and it will not be able to discharge rapidly or experience abrupt variations in load.

I think you are wrong about linear regulators and LDO rising output voltage at no load. Unregulated switching type regulators have this problem.

"I use an LDO (MIC2941A) to supply constant current" - how are you making it supply constant current? This is just a voltage regulator.

A circuit diagram would be a REALLY good idea. || Are you using the low voltage adjustable part configured as a current source ? If so it "walks funny" closer than Vout <=~ 1.235 from Vmax as the regulator cannot maintain regulation.|| If using as a 12V source wit following series resistor  it should be fine. || In either case I can't see the LDO being damaged BUT a circuit will help heaps. || Regulator is protected against reverse discharge on Vin dropping (but 0.3F is tempting fate :-) - but still should be OK.)

LDOs with fixed output should behave as per datasheet and usually maintain voltage down to zero load (in my experience). Regulators with adjustable output often require a minimum load current (as the regulator is powered by the voltage drop across the regulator) - this minimum load current is specified in the datasheet.


From experience I know that many linear regulators and LDOs will raise the output voltage if the minimum load current is not met.

All regulators have non-zero output impedance. That means that the output voltage does change a tiny bit with load. We're talking 1-10mV for your load range of 0mA..100mA. Is a change of 0.01V really too much for a supercapacitor? It's not.
But if you have experience - care to name any part numbers? Otherwise it's not very helpful.

But I wonder if there are other potential issues that could arise from not meeting the minimum load requirement.

"Recent" LDO designs usually have no minimum load requirement and are designed to support low-power applications.

Input voltage to the LDO is 12V. When the super capacitor is charged to circa 12V, there is no other load on the LDO.

LDOs are supposed to regulate voltage, not current. They limit current, yes, but they aren't meant to be used as constant-current sources. An LDO used with input voltage equal to regulation voltage will perform quite poorly. That's not what LDOs are designed for!

I use an LDO [...] to supply constant current

Why don't you use a current source?
With a low-power RRIO (rail-to-rail I/O) CMOS op-amp, it's not hard to make a simple current source that behaves rather nicely. Once the capacitor is fully charged, the source will accommodate higher current pulses than 100mA, since it will take the op-amp some time to get out of saturation. That's usually desirable. The current is nominally 100mA. R1 can be adjusted to fine-tune it. IOA1 represents the idle current consumption of the op-amp.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab


During charging, the MOSFET will dissipate 0.7W on average, 1.4W peak. An LDO would have to withstand it as well.

If we'd use an inductor to control the current, the circuit will waste very much less energy:

simulate this circuit
The comparator is a jellybean part and runs directly from 12V. It maintains about 100mA average current across the inductor:


R1 is the sense resistor for the capacitor current.
It is possible to design this circuit so that the capacitor can be connected directly to ground, and, instead the inductor current is measured. It shouldn't make much difference, since I doubt you're discharging the supercap at much more than 100mA.
